# How to work on different projects in different eclipses in parallel?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am working on two different projects in parallel.
Can I have two eclipse applications in my PC for PAF Execution?
or How to start the two projects with different directory ?
Please assist me with the solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

*Instead of parallel execution of eclipse in a local system there is another way to run two projects*

Steps:

- Create and Set up New Project in Eclipse Editor
- Once users install PAF with Editor, they can create new projects to the Project Container.
- To create new project, user need to open Eclipse and right click on the project navigator panel on left hand side, select new java project, type the project name and click Finish. The new project will be listed under  project explorer.
- To configure the PAF dependencies on the new project created, User need to navigate to the ProjectContainer folder and execute the “refreshClassPath.bat”.
- User need to input the project name where the PAF dependencies needs to be installed. Once the project configuration is complete user can create folders for drivers, scripts and execute the scripts under new Project.